# Can I use request-promise within an html page?

Tags: javascript, html, request-promise

Is it possible to use request promise like this?
if so - what is the correct way to set this up?

Would I be able to make a get request to a different domain?

I simply need to make a get request to another domain from my webpage - what would be the best way to achieve that if this way is not possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

found out you can use http://browserify.org which seems to work well